# Include html in another html file for Adsence

Tags: javascript, html, adsense

I'm trying to include my Adsense code from a file called sda.html located in the home folder of the server.

I'm using this code to include it:

```
    <div w3-include-html="../../sda.html" class="section_title text-center"></div>
```

from this source: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

but idk I feel there's something wrong.

btw my site is only HTML and js, so if there is any other better option I'll be glad to hear it.

I also checked this one down:

```
<!--#include virtual="/menu.shtml" -->
```

but I didn't use it, since I have no clue how my next server will operated. so I skip it.

and this one here:

```
<object data="../../sda.html"></object>
```

I prefer this one, but I have no control of the look of it, I couldn't center or anything

the smaller the code the better it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `sda.html` contains only adsense code or whole part of the page?

The `includeHTML` function from w3school is not very good. I suspect the issue you are having is that that function uses `innerHTML` to set content and `innerHTML` doesn't execute `<script>` tags with content: check "Security considerations" on MDN [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

To workaround this you can do the following: remove `<script>` tags from `sda.html` and then, once you imported HTML run `window.adsbygoogle.push({})` for each new ad unit. Example:

1. Add adsbygoogle.js tag in  of your page:

```
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

2. Insert ad into a div with id `div-with-ad`.

```js
const divWithAd = document.querySelector('#div-with-ad');
divWithAd.innerHTML = `
   <ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block; text-align:center;"
     data-ad-format="fluid"
     data-ad-layout="in-article"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-0123456789101112"
     data-ad-slot="9876543210"></ins>
  `;
adsbygoog.push({});
```

Comment: 1. sda.html contains only the adsense code. 2. I have no issue with the includeHTML just I don't want to use it since the code of it is very long. I'm looking for other alternatives

Comment: How does your `sda.html` looks like? Can you post it? Maybe what you want to do you can easily do from JS directly: create `<ins>` element for an ad, insert it into the page and initiate ad.

Comment: like this one: https://gist.github.com/topleague/3a4a55c925ab1de267361d08dc2cbd57

Comment: I updated my answer and added an example of how to insert an ad using JS only without loading `sda.html`.